# C# Interop Outlook Exception to OlExchangeStoreType.olExchangeMailbox

Tags: c#, exception, outlook, interop

I'm trying to access to some Shared Mailboxes(*the "Open these additional mailboxes" listing*) but I bumped into a kind of "access denied".
Make my point clear... I wrote this code:

```
IList<Store> lsStores = Application.Session.Stores.Cast<Store>().Where(c => c.ExchangeStoreType == OlExchangeStoreType.olExchangeMailbox).ToList();
```

But I have this error(in the Log folder):

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0xAD54011D): Exception
>   from HRESULT: 0xAD54011D
>          at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHRInternal(Int32
>   errorCode, IntPtr errorInfo)
>          at System.Runtime.InteropServices.CustomMarshalers.EnumeratorViewOfEnumVariant.MoveNext()
>          at System.Linq.Enumerable.d__95`1.MoveNext()
>          at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereEnumerableIterator`1.MoveNext()
>          at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
>          at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
>          at Detatchatore.Detachatore.btnAvvia_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\Me\Project\Form1.cs:line 52

In my personal computer this error doesn't show, neither my coworkers have this problem. But when I install the Application into operator pc (Application must work in his pc), I have this exception.
Thanks, and sorry for my poor English.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I'd recommend avoiding any LINQ queries with Outlook objects. Moreover, I'd suggest releasing them in a timely manner, i.e. as soon as possible. You may find the following links helpful:

- [Systematically Releasing Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb623945%28office.12%29.aspx) - is related to Outlook, but the same principles can be applied to any other Office application.
- [When to release COM objects in Office add-ins developed in .NET](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2008/10/30/releasing-office-objects-net/)

Second, you need to break the chain of property or method calls and declare each property or method on a separate line of code. Thus, you will be able to find the problematic one if the code fails.